# Can AWS Quicksight remember control / filter setting per user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I have an **AWS QuickSight dashboard** defined with a [parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/parameters-set-up.html) having dynamic defaults per user. The dashboard contains a **filter** defined by the **parameter** with corresponding **control**.

Is there any possibility to remember the setting of the controls / filters for each user, so next time when they view the dashboard the previous setting will be the default?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Filter and parameter persistence was launched in late 2020.  The default behavior for all users is that dashboards will look exactly the same as how they left it the last time.

For embedded dashboards you can turn persistence on or off when calling the API to get the embedded dashboard URL (there is a StatePersistenceEnabled value you can set to TRUE/FALSE in that command).
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/API_GetDashboardEmbedUrl.html

Answer (score 0):

As of today according to AWS Support this feature is not available in Amazon QuickSight.